# Could not open or start AVI movie file

Tags: rendering

I got a error when i rendered the animation that said "Could not open or start AVI movie file" And I need to know how to fix it. And i do not know how to close the AVI movie file.

Comment: what program were you trying to open the avi in?

Answer (score 1):

I have made the experience that it has something to do with the corresponding file's user rights. Usually this occurs after rendering and not finishing an animation in an avi file.

You could try changing the filename of the animation you are trying to render (e.g. instead of "0001-0250.avi" change it to "new_name.avi" in the render output tab). Another possibility could be to delete your previous avi from the rendering directory and restart the render.

[image]

Comment: adegner is a genius.
he suggested to change the name after rendering if you want to render agian and it works.